# Javascript/jQuery - Changing object data attribute doesn't stop video playing in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome

I have an object like below:

```
<object data="black.html" width="100%" class="vidlink vid1link"></object>
```

I am then using the following code to load a youtube video:

```
$(".vid1link").attr("data", "https://www.youtube.com/embed/MhKxm_G6FRw?autoplay=1");
```

This works great. But then I want the user to "close the video". The following code triggers the data attribute to change to a black page:

```
$(".vid1link").attr('data', 'black.html');
```

This works in fine on Firefox and IE/Edge. But on chrome the video continues to play. I have checked the elements in the console, and it is successfully replacing the data with black.html, but it still continues to play the video, as mentioned, only in Chrome.

Is this a known bug or normal chrome behaviour?

Many thanks

EDIT: For now I have found a work around by sending a pause request to the youtube video:

Add the following to the youtube link: **enablejsapi=1**

```
this.contentWindow.postMessage('{"event":"command","func":"stopVideo","args":""}', '*')
```

Although - this doesn't seem to work if there are multiple videos on the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('.vid1link').replaceWith('<object data="black.html" width="100%" class="vidlink vid1link"></object>');
```

You need to remove completely old element before replace the attribute

Answer (score 0):

```
    document.getElementsByClassName(".vid1link").setAttribute('data', 'black.html');
```

Comment: How is this any different from what OP has already tried, other than not using jquery, it appears to do exactly the same thing.

Comment: You can also try to clear cache in your browser.  Go to settings  the advanced then you delete cache. be carefull though just check the cache  checkbox

Comment: Javascript is updated now and then there things i can not do with #id anymore i have to define with $(document).on('click', '#id', ()=>{}); i think you get me the old way is not working at all i could do the same statement like $('#id').click(()=>{});

Comment: @JerubaalXerxes - I have the console set to disable cache, also tried in an incognito window

Comment: if you have nested div's meaning a div inside a div inside a div then you are eventlistening from a button of the last child this is the only way